# How to solve SQL connection string issues?

Tags: mysql, vb.net, connection-string

I'm experienced with both VB.NET and SQL, but I've never worked with both at the same time before. I've found dozens of online tutorials, most of which contradict each other and none of which I can get to work. I now have a sizable project on the brink of completion except for the SQL functionality and I'm at my wits end trying to solve it.

Here's my code:

```
Imports System.IO        'Most of these aren't relevant to this,
Imports EAGetMail        'but I thought it best to leave them in.
Imports System.Data.Linq
Imports System.Data.Linq.Mapping
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.Configuration
Imports Microsoft.Office.Core

Public Sub testSQL()
    Try
        Dim connStr As String
        connStr = "server=localhost;database=MyAwesomeDB;uid=Bruce Wayne;pwd=B@+m@n;persistsecurityinfo=True;"
        'connStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("PMC.My.MySettings.DatabaseC­onnectionString").ConnectionString

        Dim SQLConn As New SqlConnection()
        Dim SQLCmd As New SqlCommand()

        SQLConn.ConnectionString = connStr
        SQLConn.Open()

        SQLCmd.Connection = SQLConn
        SQLCmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Users VALUES ('SpacePimp','ZapAHo',69,255);"
        SQLCmd.ExecuteNonQuery() 

        SQLConn.Close()
        MsgBox("Success!")
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Failure" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

I've tried tweaking the connection string with every possible combination of variations I've seen in online tutorials (using ' or an escaped " for the parameter values, interchanging pwd with password/etc., specifying the port (with localhost:3306) and creating a user/password with only alphabetic characters), but always I get the same error: Cannot connect to SQL Server (Error 40). The commented connection string is a method I tried to follow from a tutorial which uses the connection already established in VS, but the syntax or namespace seems to have changed since the time this method was posted, as 'ConfigurationManager' is unknown to the compiler.

I'm deeply grateful for any help anyone can provide.

Comment: You talk about MySql but your code uses the classes that are specific for working with Sql Server. If your backend db is MySql you need to download their NET/Connector, install it and reference it in your project and finally change every SqlConnection, SqlCommand to MySqlConnection and MySqlCommand. Also your connection string doesn't seems to be valid for MySql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, Steve. Adding

```
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient
```

and changing all the SqlCommand / SqlConnection variables to MySqlCommand / MySqlConnection did the trick.